# Where is "Developer Information" shown by Mac OS X System Profiler coming from?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I was trying to see if I can run latest Xcode 4.2 on a machine running Snow Leopard 10.6.0 by just copying the /Developer folder from my macbook running 10.6.8. So I renamed an existing /Developer folder with Xcode 3.2 to /Developer.old and copied the /Developer with new Xcode from the other box. Changing "Minimum system version" to 10.6.0 in the Info.plist in Xcode's package sort of did the trick, I can run Xcode, but I have a problem with running iPhone apps in iPhone Simulator. It gets stuck on "Attaching to MyApp".

So, I guess something is missing in my "installation". I noticed System Profiler is showing the old version of Xcode in Developer Information, better yet, it points to /Developer.old. How could I update this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode and iPhone Simulator is extremely picky about the OS version. If it says it needs 10.6.8, it needs some functionality present in 10.6.8 but not in 10.6.0. So, don't try to fight with the rule and just use 10.6.8.

That said, you should note that XCode installation is not just in `/Developer`. You also have commandline tools which is installed in various places, and some support data in `/Library/Developer`. You can inspect what is installed where by having a look at the XCode installer package. I think some of the command line tools are responsible for the info in the System Profiler.

But, let me say again: XCode and iPhone Simulator is extremely picky about the OS version. If it says it needs 10.6.8, it needs some functionality present in 10.6.8 but not in 10.6.0. So, don't try to fight with the rule and just use 10.6.8.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I copied contents of /Library/Developer as well. I'm happy to report that I actually managed to build a project using Xcode 4.2 on my Snow Leopard 10.6.0 and run it on my iPod Touch (I'm a registered iOS developer). No success with running the app in iPhone Simulator yet, though.

Comment: Why do you want to use 10.6.0?

Comment: The machine is Samsung NB30 netbook. I installed SL 10.6.0 on it using NetbookInstaller 0.8.4 and it works fine, apart from minor issues like no sound and the fact that I had to replace wifi card with a Mac OS X compatible one. Unfortunately updating the system turned out to be really hard, as NB30 is not supported by NetbookInstaller and the machines' DSDT needs to be patched, I think.